# When a condition is met, show current row value on each line below it, where the condition is not met

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

is it possible via either Power Query or Power Pivot to get from following table

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
|  | Category1 |
| 1 | Task1 |
| 2 | Task2 |
|  | Category2 |
| 3 | Task3 |
| 4 | Task4 |

a table, where the category is in a separate column for each row under it?

| ID | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | Category1 |
| 2 | Task2 | Category1 |
| 3 | Task3 | Category2 |
| 4 | Task4 | Category2 |

I have tried to do it with some indexed columns or FIRSTNONBLANK but I have failed miserably.

Comment: It can be easily done in excel. Do you want to automate it with powerquery for repetitive use or just once?

Comment: Repetitive use. I would like to avoid VBA if possible. I know how to do it there, but I want to know if it is possible in PQ/PP/PBI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate method

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Category", each if [ID]=null then [Description] else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Description.1", each if [ID]<>null then [Description] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Category"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Description"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Description.1] <> null))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is absolutely possible with PQWRY

```
    let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577466/when-a-condition-is-met-show-current-row-value-on-each-line-below-it-where-the"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}}, [RowSelector="DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Description", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each Text.StartsWith([Description], "Category")),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "catIndex", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Description", "Index"}, #"Added Index1", {"Description", "Index"}, "Added Index1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Index1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Index1", {"catIndex"}, {"catIndex"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded Added Index1",{"catIndex"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"catIndex"}, {{"ad", each _, type table [ID=nullable number, Description=nullable text, catIndex=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each let x = [ad],
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(x,{{"Description", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows1", "Custom", each #"Sorted Rows1"[Description]{0}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Description] <> #"Sorted Rows1"[Description]{0})),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"ID", "Description", "Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Custom", "Category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"catIndex", "ad"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"ID", "Description", "Category"}, {"ID", "Description", "Category"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

[image: Solution]